# What would be the best way to respond to thank you and a compliment at the same time?

Tags: politeness, conversations

I helped someone online translate something from English into Japanese and they responded with:

> ありがとうございます！
>
> イラスト素敵です " (<* i do illustrations)

I want to say "thank you very much!" but idk if I should just reply with "ありがとうございます" or it would be rude to just say the same thing and/or to not address their "thank you" first with something like "いつでもどうぞ" and then a "thank you" or would that still be... weird? (I did tell them my Japanese is not very good beforehand)

Would it be ok if I reply with:

> どういたしまして
>
> もありがとうございます

What would be the best way to reply in this situation?

Comment: `もありがとうございます` <- What did you mean by the も ?

Comment: "and thank you" or "thank you too" (?) forgive me im still learning

Comment: も is only attached to the end of nouns. You can't begin a sentence with it.

Comment: In situations like these I like to use どういたしまして。*恐縮*です。(which as far as I know sounds a bit over-the-top but always causes a good reaction smh)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could first address their thank you and then thank them for their compliment, like..

> いえいえ、どういたしまして。
>
> イラスト、お褒めいただきありがとうございます。
> or イラスト、褒めてくださってありがとうございます。

If you just wrote ありがとうございます after どういたしまして, it would be unclear what you're thanking for, so I suggest adding イラスト、お褒めいただき or 褒めてくださって... which is the polite way (honorific/humble form) of saying 褒めてもらって or 褒めてくれて. Alternatively I think you could say イラスト、気に入ってくださって嬉しいです。

Comment: You mean どういたしまして not どうしたしまして right?

Comment: ^ うええ。。打ち間違ったぁ・・ありがとうございます！